# The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to TileSet

Tags: java

I am trying to program a Java RPG game, but the `tileSet` Loader won't work. 
Here is the code:

```
TileSet tileSet1 = new TileSet("/tiles/rpg.png", 12, 12, 0, null);
Level level = new Level(this, "/level/level1.txt", tileSet);
```

That is causing errors. And this should be executed through it, but the problem is that it is an array. But it needs to be an array for other methods in the class:

```
public Level(Game game, String path, TileSet[] ts1) {
  this.game = game;
  this.ts = ts1;
  String file = Utils.loadFileAsString(path);
  String[] tokens = file.split("\\s");
  sizeY = Utils.parseInt(tokens[1]);
  tileMap = new int[1][sizeX][sizeY];
  int i = 2;
  for(int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++){
      tileMap[0][x][y] = Utils.parseInt(tokens[i++]);
    }
  }
}
```

Why might this be?

Comment: What `TileSet` is ?

Comment: I wonder how we should be able to help here. You passed a single `TileSet` to the constructor and you wrote that constructor to expect an array. We don't know why you only pass a single one or why you wrote the constructor to expect an array and what it is supposed to do with that.

Comment: @Tom ahh yes, I didn't notice that it was a constructor. Bad formatting does that. Well he/she should be able to solve this alone.

Comment: So, the TileSet is an Set of Tiles, used to generate or create a Map. I need help with that constructor. :O

Comment: As was said before: the constructor expects a `TileSet[]`, but you pass as `TileSet`. The tyes do not match. A quick & dirty fix would be to change `TileSet[] ts1` to `TileSet... ts1` (that is called a varargs, see [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more information). But I would expect that this breaks something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor is expecting an array in last parameter, but you passed just single object. Try to wrap it into array like :

```
Level level = new Level(this, "/level/level1.txt", new TileSet[]{tileSet});
```

Comment: No sorry, That didnt worked. Its still an grey window.
So. now this error comes up (not from IDE)
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at de.gandalf1783.Level.getTilesTouched(Level.java:37)
 at de.gandalf1783.Creature.move(Creature.java:33)
 at de.gandalf1783.Player.update(Player.java:19)
 at de.gandalf1783.Game.update(Game.java:84)
 at de.gandalf1783.Game.run(Game.java:54)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Everything of it is posted here,

Comment: @Gandalf1783 That's a different problem. Ruslan's answer solves the problem that you asked for in your question above.

Comment: Yes, but it when i got a new problem i'll ask for more help. Of course thanks for that solution but its not gone at all....

Comment: @Gandalf1783 Just ask one more *new* question if you have one. And read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before. We all ready to help :)

Comment: @Gandalf1783 If a new question arises, please ask a new question. Otherwise, you may invalidate already existing answers. Also, please take the [Tour].